# Does the reference variable in Java have any size?

Tags: java, c

In C++ we used `sizeof()` operator, which function can we use in Java to check the size of an object?

My basic doubt is that whether the reference variable in java has any size or not. Consider the following example:

```
SampleClass obj = new SampleClass();
```

Here, will `obj` have any size? If yes, How can we check it in Java?

Comment: There is no `sizeof` in java. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The reference variable `obj` itself surely has a size in the implementation, but this should be constant, no matter what the referenced object is (depending on the implementation it would be something like a pointer/memory address) and it is not the same as the size of the referenced object, which is only known at runtime. It would be interesting why you want to know any size, as it is highly implementation (that of the VM) dependent and Java is definitely not the language for such low-level things.

Comment: vstm..i just want to know whether the reference variable has any size or not ??

Comment: @AnitSingh Then rest assured that it has a size, although there won't be a platform-independent answer on how large this size is, but there definitely should be one. Maybe the compiler can optimize some reference variables away as being just aliases for others, but in general `obj` has to have a size, as it has to somehow store the reference (whatever this is, it is something and not nothing).

Comment: @Christian Rau...superb comment sir :)

Comment: You may find the [JavaSpecialists 092](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue029.html) newsletter on _Determining Memory Usage_ by Heinz M. Kabutz helpful.

Answer (score 3):

`obj` is a variable, not an object. The *value* of `obj` is a reference - which is likely to be 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the JVM.

The size of the object that the value refers to is *also* JVM-dependent. As several objects can refer to each other, it's generally tricky to talk about the size of an object in Java in any particularly useful way... what usually matters is how much more memory would be potentially available if a particular object became eligible for garbage collection, and that depends on what other objects the first object refers to - and whether there are *other* objects that refer to those, too.

Obviously the "raw" size of an object is somewhat important too, and at least *somewhat* easier to predict (to an approximation, at least), but it's still VM-specific and can't easily be requested at execution time. (You could create millions of objects, prevent them from being garbage collected, and measure memory differences, but that's the closest I know of, at least outside a debugger API.)

Answer (score 2):

Since you found my comment superb, I just had to post it as an answer, although it may be superflous to the already existing answers:

Rest assured that a reference variable (like `obj`) has a size, although there won't be a platform-independent answer on how large this size is, but there definitely should be a size. But due to this platform (or JVM) dependence, Java is not the language to mess with such low-level details.

Maybe the compiler can optimize some reference variables away as being just aliases for others, but in general `obj` has to have a size, as it has to somehow store the reference (whatever this is, it is something and not nothing).

Answer (score 1):

`obj` is only the reference to an instance of `SampleClass`.

The size that the instance of SampleClass occupies in the memory depends on the elements the files of the object, and VM. But even a reference need some memory of course (like in c)

But the java memory model is much more complicated. If you are really interessted in how much memory the object need, then I strongly recommend to use a memory analyzer.

Anyway: because java is a VM and the Java VM has the garbage collector, there is no real 1:1 relation ship between the size of the memory you would expect by counting the (living) java objects and the memory the VM allocates from the Operation System.

Comment: How could i use a memory analyzer, isn't there a simple method to check size of a reference variable ??

Comment: Memory Analyzer are (big) software, that shows the status of an vm. @see: http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ for an good one

Answer (score 0):

You might try getting some insight on the "size" of the reference by using the `freeMemory` method of the `Runtime` class.
For example, allocate an array of 1000000 null references:

```
SampleClass[] array = new SampleClass[1000000];
```

Check the free memory before and after; the difference may give a hint on what you want to know (the array itself is an object, though its size is probably much less than 1000000, so the measurement must be pretty precise).